# How can I add a value to an array by referencing the HashMap containing it in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, iteration

Here's my data set:

```
<zoo>
  <animal type="dog" breed="beagle" name="charlie" />
  <animal type="dog" breed="beagle" name="chester" />
  <animal type="dog" breed="retriever" name="goldie" />
  <animal type="duck" breed="mallard" name="lord quackerton" />
</zoo>
```

I want to transform this data into a big Java object, a hashmap of hashmaps of arrays.  Toward that end, I've written the following code:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> expectedTypes = new HashMap();
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> expectedBreeds = new HashMap();
ArrayList<String> expectedNames = new ArrayList();

// Each <animal> element has already been stored in an array called 'zoo'
for( int i = 0; i < zoo.length; i++) {
    // Grab string values from XML file, using XMLbeans:
    String thisExpectedType = tests[i].getType();
    String thisExpectedBreed = tests[i].getBreed();
    String thisExpectedName = tests[i].getName();

    // Store grabbed strings into the proposed object:
    expectedNames.add(thisExpectedName);
    expectedBreeds.put(thisExpectedBreed, expectedNames);
    expectedTypes.put(thisExpectedType, expectedBreeds);
}
```

This is *almost* doing what I want.  The HashMaps get set up fine, but at the bottom level they're all storing the same `expectedNames` array.  It looks like this:

```
- dog
  - beagle
    - 0 charlie
    - 1 chester
    - 2 goldie
    - 3 lord quackerton
  - retriever
    - 0 charlie
    - 1 chester
    - 2 goldie
    - 3 lord quackerton
- duck
  - mallard
    - 0 charlie
    - 1 chester
    - 2 goldie
    - 3 lord quackerton
```

But here's what I need:

```
- dog
  - beagle
    - 0 charlie
    - 1 chester
  - retriever
    - 0 goldie
- duck
  - mallard
    - 0 lord quackerton
```

I think I need to see if `thisExpectedBreed` at `i` already exists and if it doesn't, make a new array and put that in the HashMap.  But how can I do that?  How can I make sure each `expectedBreeds` Map has its own unique array and add the values to each array correctly?

If it helps, the data set is sorted by `type`, then `breed`, then `name`, so the logic won't have to anticipate any jumping around.  Once one `breed` has been catalogued, for example, I won't have to handle any more elements of that `breed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a set of names for each map, instead of reusing the same set of names

```
// Each <animal> element has already been stored in an array called 'zoo'
for( int i = 0; i < zoo.length; i++) 
{
    ...

    // get the names for this breed
    ArrayList<String> expectedNames = expectedBreeds.get(thisExpectedBreed);
    // if there aren't any, start a new collection
    if (expectedNames == null)
    {
        expectedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        expectedBreeds.put(thisExpectedBreed, expectedNames);
    }
    expectedNames.add(thisExpectedName);
    ...
```

right now you're reusing the same names across all of the animals

Comment: This was the right idea.  It turned out I needed to move the nested HashMap into the loop, too, so it got pretty gnarly.  I'll post the corrected code in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 1:1 mapping between the XML and a map of maps (of maps...) you are much better off using a tool like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) that does the XML -> java object mapping for you. Read about it, you won't be disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to move the array and internal HashMap instantiations into the loop, as *@John Gardner* recommended:

```
// Set up the top-level HashMap
Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> expectedTypes = new HashMap();

// Each <animal> element has already been stored in an array called 'zoo'
for( int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
  // Grab string values from XML file, using XMLbeans:
  String thisExpectedType = tests[i].getType();
  String thisExpectedBreed = tests[i].getBreed();
  String thisExpectedName = tests[i].getName();

  // get the breeds for this type:
  Map<String, ArrayList<String>> expectedBreeds = expectedTypes.get(thisExpectedType);
  // if there aren't any, start a new collection:
  if(expectedBreeds == null) {
      expectedBreeds = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
      expectedTypes.put(thisExpectedType, expectedBreeds);
  }

  // get the names for this breed:
  ArrayList<String> expectedNames = expectedBreeds.get(thisExpectedBreed);
  // if there aren't any, start a new collection:
  if(expectedNames == null) {
      expectedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
      expectedBreeds.put(thisExpectedBreed, expectedNames);
  }
  expectedNames.add(thisExpectedName);

      expectedBreeds.put(thisExpectedBreed, expectedNames);
      expectedTypes.put(thisExpectedType, expectedBreeds);
}
```